# First chern class of fibers of compact Kaehler algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, algebraic-curves, kahler-manifolds

Let $M$ be an compact Kähler algebraic variety and suppose $K_M$ is semi-ample. Consider the holomorphic map $\pi:X\to \Sigma \subset \mathbb CP^N$ with $Kod(M)=dim_\mathbb C\Sigma$ (here $Kod$ means Kodaira dimension). Does a nonsingular fibre $\pi^{-1}(z)$ has vanishing first Chern class? What about the first Chern class of singular fibers?

Comment: This kind of question is better suited to math.stackexhange.com, and you'll get more detailed answers there.

Answer (score 6):

> Does a nonsingular fibre $\pi^{−1}(z)$ has vanishing first Chern class?

Yes. Denote a regular fiber $Z$; then 
$K_M|_ Z= det(N^*Z)\otimes K_Z= K_Z$
by adjunction formula. On the other hand, 
$K_M$ is trivial on $Z$, because it is a pullback
from the base, and $Z$ is a fiber.

This argument proves vanishing of rational $c_1$. For
integer $c_1$, the statement is wrong: consider a product
of Enriques surface and a curve of genus $g>1$, its canonical
bundle is semiample, but the fibers of the corresponding projections
are Enriques surfaces, having torsion $c_1$.

> What about the first Chern class of singular fibers?

If the map is flat, yes, but not otherwise
(take a blowup, for example).

Comment: I guess the hypothesis gives only that some multiple $K_M^{\otimes n}$ is a pullback, so $K_Z^{\otimes n}$ is trivial, which gives $c_1=0$ in rational cohomology.

Comment: sure, I meant the rational $c_1$. No idea about integer $c_1$, it's an iteresting question actually.

Comment: added a counterexample for integer $c_1$, just a product of Enriques and a curve